# Convert string to datatime object in r

Tags: r, date

I have a list of strings `times`. I want to convert those strings to datetime object. I tried `as.POSIXct` and did not get expected outcomes. I want datetimes like this `00:30, 01:30` ect...

Is there any easy code for doing this?

```
> times
 [1] "00:30" "01:30" "02:30" "03:30" "04:30" "05:30" "06:30" "07:30" "08:30" "09:30" "10:30" "11:30" "12:30" "13:30" "14:30"
[16] "15:30" "16:30" "17:30" "18:30" "19:30" "20:30" "21:30" "22:30" "23:30"
> times <- as.POSIXct(times, format = '%H:%M')
 [1] "2020-03-11 00:30:00 CDT" "2020-03-11 01:30:00 CDT" "2020-03-11 02:30:00 CDT" "2020-03-11 03:30:00 CDT"
 [5] "2020-03-11 04:30:00 CDT" "2020-03-11 05:30:00 CDT" "2020-03-11 06:30:00 CDT" "2020-03-11 07:30:00 CDT"
 [9] "2020-03-11 08:30:00 CDT" "2020-03-11 09:30:00 CDT" "2020-03-11 10:30:00 CDT" "2020-03-11 11:30:00 CDT"
[13] "2020-03-11 12:30:00 CDT" "2020-03-11 13:30:00 CDT" "2020-03-11 14:30:00 CDT" "2020-03-11 15:30:00 CDT"
[17] "2020-03-11 16:30:00 CDT" "2020-03-11 17:30:00 CDT" "2020-03-11 18:30:00 CDT" "2020-03-11 19:30:00 CDT"
[21] "2020-03-11 20:30:00 CDT" "2020-03-11 21:30:00 CDT" "2020-03-11 22:30:00 CDT" "2020-03-11 23:30:00 CDT"
```

Comment: Your code looks good. Datetimes need dates---not just times. Is your question how to print a datetime in your original format? You can use `format(times, format = "%H:%M")`.

Comment: Well, in the end, those hour and minute times, i.e. `00:30, 01:30...` will be x axis in ggplot. I am not sure whether ggplot can recognize those characters as date objects. PS, I checked your code `format`, after which `times` became `character` again....

Comment: You cannot have `00:30, 01:30` as date-time (`POSIXct` ) objects.

Comment: Yeah... knowing that your issue is a plot label is pretty key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As previous comments and answers suggested, the `POSIXct` (i.e., datetime) class in `R` always stores dates along with times. If you convert from a character object with just times to that class, today's date is added by default (if you want another date, you could do, for example, this: `as.POSIXct(paste("2020-01-01", times), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")`).

However, this should almost never be a problem since you can use `format(times, format = "%H:%M")` or for `ggplot2` `scale_x_datetime` to get just the times back. For plotting, this would look something like this:

```r
times <- c("00:30", "01:30", "02:30", "03:30", "04:30", "05:30", "06:30", "07:30", "08:30", "09:30", "10:30", "11:30", "12:30", "13:30", "14:30",
           "15:30", "16:30", "17:30", "18:30", "19:30", "20:30", "21:30", "22:30", "23:30")

library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(
  time_chr = times,
  time = as.POSIXct(times, format = "%H:%M"),
  value = rnorm(length(times))
)
df
#> # A tibble: 24 x 3
#>    time_chr time                 value
#>    <chr>    <dttm>               <dbl>
#>  1 00:30    2020-03-12 00:30:00  0.352
#>  2 01:30    2020-03-12 01:30:00 -0.547
#>  3 02:30    2020-03-12 02:30:00 -0.574
#>  4 03:30    2020-03-12 03:30:00  0.843
#>  5 04:30    2020-03-12 04:30:00  0.798
#>  6 05:30    2020-03-12 05:30:00 -0.620
#>  7 06:30    2020-03-12 06:30:00  0.213
#>  8 07:30    2020-03-12 07:30:00  1.21 
#>  9 08:30    2020-03-12 08:30:00  0.370
#> 10 09:30    2020-03-12 09:30:00  0.497
#> # … with 14 more rows

ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = value)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%H:%M")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In *base* you can use `as.difftime` to *convert a string to time object*:

```
as.difftime(times, "%H:%M")
#Time differences in mins
# [1]   30   90  150  210  270  330  390  450  510  570  630  690  750  810  870
#[16]  930  990 1050 1110 1170 1230 1290 1350 1410
```

You can also use the `hms` package:

```
library(hms)
head(as_hms(paste0(times, ":00")))
#00:30:00
#01:30:00
#02:30:00
#03:30:00
#04:30:00
#05:30:00
```

or the `lubridate` package as already suggested by [@jpmam1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60646863/10488504)

```
library(lubridate)
hm(times)
# [1] "30M 0S"     "1H 30M 0S"  "2H 30M 0S"  "3H 30M 0S"  "4H 30M 0S" 
# [6] "5H 30M 0S"  "6H 30M 0S"  "7H 30M 0S"  "8H 30M 0S"  "9H 30M 0S" 
#[11] "10H 30M 0S" "11H 30M 0S" "12H 30M 0S" "13H 30M 0S" "14H 30M 0S"
#[16] "15H 30M 0S" "16H 30M 0S" "17H 30M 0S" "18H 30M 0S" "19H 30M 0S"
#[21] "20H 30M 0S" "21H 30M 0S" "22H 30M 0S" "23H 30M 0S"
```

`as.POSIXct` stores dates with your times. If you need it only for plotting that will cause no problem and use the answer from [@JBGruber](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60650923/10488504). Storing dates where there are no dates should be avoided or the dates should be set to values where it is clear that they are wrong.

```
head(as.POSIXct(paste("9999-1-1", times)))
#[1] "9999-01-01 00:30:00 CET" "9999-01-01 01:30:00 CET"
#[3] "9999-01-01 02:30:00 CET" "9999-01-01 03:30:00 CET"
#[5] "9999-01-01 04:30:00 CET" "9999-01-01 05:30:00 CET"
```